# How to set width and height to jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, jplayer

I am using jPlayer library but i don't know how to set width and height

My code is :

```
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function(){
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"
                        }).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    ended: function(event){
                        // $(this).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    swfPath: "../../common/assets/jplayer/js",
                    supplied: "m4v"

                });
```

Please help me.

Comment: where you at with this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Untested, I think your code should look something like this:

```
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function(){
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"
                        }).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    ended: function(){
                         $(this).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    swfPath: "../../common/assets/jplayer/js",
                    supplied: "m4v",
                    size: {
                         width: "400px",
                         height: "30px"
                    }
                });
```

I noticed that you were trying to loop the file?   I changed the function call since it doesn't seem like you need the (event).

You should read this: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-size
The sizes change according to the file types given.

Answer (score 11):

the `width` and `height` constructor options mentioned in the previous answers will only affect the dimensions of the `#jquery_jplayer_1` element itself which contains the poster image (if audio) or video content..

those options do not affect your GUI (everything else - controls, playlist etc.), the size of which is controlled by CSS.

If you are using one of the demo jPlayer skins (e.g. "Blue Monday") you need very specific CSS selectors to override their rules, or to use the `!important` flag..

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-size) says:

> Set the width and height of jPlayer using
>   the `jPlayer({size:Object})` constructor option.
>
> The full-screen size is set using the `jPlayer({sizeFull:Object})`
>   constructor option.

whereas

> **width**
>   String : (Default: [Video:"480px"] [Audio:"0px"])
>
> **height**
>   String : (Default: [Video:"270px"] [Audio:"0px"])

That means something like

```
jPlayer({size:{width: "200px", height: "200px"}})
```

and complete:

```
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function(){
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"
                        }).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    ended: function(event){
                        // $(this).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    swfPath: "../../common/assets/jplayer/js",
                    supplied: "m4v",
                    size: {width: "200px", height: "200px"}
                });
```